QBXML - How to modify Item Line custom field (DataExtValue)
When trying with QBXML to modify the custom field value of an item line, I get the error: The specified custom field cannot be used by the list or transaction element.
My custom field relates to items and not to lists.
My code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="15.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <DataExtModRq>
            <DataExtMod>
                <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                <DataExtName>Writer</DataExtName>
                <TxnDataExtType>Check</TxnDataExtType>
                <TxnID>2AFBD-1705454810</TxnID>
                <TxnLineID>38DDB-1705454810</TxnLineID>
                <DataExtValue>3</DataExtValue>
            </DataExtMod>
        </DataExtModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>

